# ChromeDriver window doesn't readjust the size to fit Nexus 5's dimensions

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm currently using:

```
options.EnableMobileEmulation("Nexus 5");
```

To emulate a mobile version of a website, but ChromeDriver window doesn't readjust the size to fit Nexus 5's dimensions so I'm left with half a blank page.

Example:

[image]

I want window size to fit the content of the site rather than producing empty page content.

Comment: Why is it an issue?

Comment: @FlorentB. just looks untidy and would be nice information to know, for future preferences as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
System.Drawing.Size window_size = new System.Drawing.Size(x, y);
driver.Manage().Window.Size = window_size;
```

where x, y: width and height in pixels.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Remember that the arguments to `Size`'s constructor are integers, not strings.